# How to sort a a table with Javascript without library?

Tags: javascript, html

There is two main aims:

1. Sort table of data using javascript without libraries such as jquery, so pure javascript.
2. Sort/group rows together based on class/id (like css).

I thought maybe getElementById could be useful, but don't know enough javascript to investigate properly.

Comment: I'm not sure about `getElementById`, but I would probably start with something like...`<script>` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

A table's rows can be found in the `rows[]` array of said table.

You can create an array containing those rows.

You can then `.sort()` the array based on a callback function that looks up certain info, in the form
`.sort(function(a,b) { /* return -1 if a comes before b or 1 if b comes before a */ })`

If you iterate over the array and `appendChild` the rows to the table they are in, the result is a sorted table.

If you have problems with the actual code, please post what you have so far and we can help more specifically ;)

Comment: I don't want to do it in php because I want to put the onus on the visitor browser to conduct the sort rather than process an array on the backend, unless are you talking about javascript?

Comment: @Stephen "He" is correct, although thank you for not assuming either way ;)

Comment: "This is some pretty basic stuff" ok I feel even dumber than I did before, im sure that was not as intended :) Thanks Kolink, I will do more research ;)..